# Python Multiprocessing Memory Leak

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've searched all over stackoverflow for answers about python multiprocessing but have yet to find a solution to my memory leak.

As far as I know, `map_async` and `map` will close the worker and release memory per each file in my list of files. Why is that my memory usage continues to increase when the code below is run?

```
number_of_workers = 4

files = []  
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    files.append(file)

def bleualign(file):
    cmd = "python3 '../bleualign/bleualign.py' -f file -params X"
    os.system(cmd)
    cmd = "python3 '../bleualign/bleualign.py' -f file -params Y"
    os.system(cmd)

def multicore():
    mypool = Pool(processes=number_of_workers, maxtasksperchild=1)
    mypool.map_async(bleualign, files, chunksize=1)
    mypool.close()
    mypool.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    multicore()
```

Comment: Your workers don't even use that file variable.

Comment: So why do you think ‘python’ is the problem?

Comment: @barny After more debugging, I'm starting to think the memory leak is with bleualign.py

Comment: @Sraw doesn't "mypool.map_async(bleualign, files, chunksize=1)" take in files array appended with each file?

Comment: Oh. really? Can't say that's too much of a surprise.